# Jenkins does not display the current config

Tags: jenkins, ubuntu-12.04

I am currently figthing with Jenkins. I use Ubuntu Server 12.04 and installed from the official apt-repository (package jenkins). Everything went fine and I can access the GUI.

When I started to configure the system (e.g. /configure) I noticed that the system seems to not store the values I configured. I then checked the configfiles. It turned out that Jenkins is storing the correct config but is always displaying the default config.

I have checked the logfiles in /var/log/jenkins but did not find any hint.

I am thankfull for any help.

Take care,
Alex

As I am not allowed to answer my own question at the moment:
It seems as if I have solved the problem. What I did:

```
1. apt-get purge jenkins
2. Checked that everything is deleted
3. Add Jenkins Repository (http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian-stable/)
4. apt-get update
5. apt-get install jenkins
```

I am not sure why but this solved my problem. It might be as well a distubring browser cache which prevented the GUI from updating...

Cheers, Alex

Answer (score 0):

As answered by [AlexWerz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1808555/alexwerz) himself:

"It seems as if I have solved the problem.

What I did:

```
1. apt-get purge jenkins
2. Checked that everything is deleted
3. Add Jenkins Repository (http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian-stable/)
4. apt-get update
5. apt-get install jenkins
```

I am not sure why but this solved my problem.
It might be as well a distubring browser cache which prevented the GUI from updating...

Cheers, Alex"